# Load image into FileReader

Tags: javascript, filereader

I want to load an image from an url into filereader in order to obtain a data url of that image. I tried to search for the solution on google but i can only find solutions to read them from the file input on a local computer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want a usable data-URI representation of the image, then I suggest to load the image in a `<img>` tag, paint it on a `<canvas>` then use the `.toDataURL()` method of the canvas.

Otherwise, you need to use `XMLHttpRequest` to get the image blob (set the `responseType` property on the XMLHttpRequest instance and get the blob from the `.response` property). Then, you can use the `FileReader` API as usual.

In both cases, the images have to be hosted on the same origin, or CORS must be enabled.

If your server does not support CORS, you can use a proxy that adds CORS headers. In the following example (using the second method), I'm using [CORS Anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) to get CORS headers on any image I want.

```
var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
x.open('GET', '//cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.youtube.com/favicon.ico');
x.responseType = 'blob';
x.onload = function() {
    var blob = x.response;
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onloadend = function() {
        var dataUrl = fr.result;
        // Paint image, as a proof of concept
        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.src = dataUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(blob);
};
x.send();
```

The previous code can be copy-pasted to the console, and you will see a small image with YouTube's favicon at the bottom of the page. Link to demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4Y7VP/

Comment: Is there a solution without CORS enabled?

Comment: @user Use a CORS proxy. See my updated answer, with an example.

Comment: This is awesome thanks! I've been trying to get the orientation from an remote image's exif but it kept failing since I was using the canvas to get the base64 so that then I could convert it to a blob/file. But this way I can just get the blob directly from the server and then get the orientation from the blob.

Comment: @RobW, are there any caveats to using a proxy server method in production?

Comment: @OksanaRomaniv Yes. If it is a third-party one, then there is a risk of availability (there is no guarantee that your requests will always be handled as expected). If self-hosted, then you need to make sure that only your application is allowed to use the proxy, and only to a limited, known set of destinations.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative download with fetch:

```
fetch('http://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://lorempixel.com/640/480/? 
    60789', {
    headers: {},
}).then((response) => {
   return response.blob();
}).then((blob) => {
    console.log(blob);
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onloadend = function() {
       var dataUrl = fr.result;
       // Paint image, as a proof of concept
       var img = document.createElement('img');
       img.src = dataUrl;
       document.body.appendChild(img);
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(blob);
}).catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Comment: use https whenever possible. use `URL.createObjectURL` instead of using the FileReader to display images.