# Get image data from (blob) from the img tag (opposite method to URL.createObjectURL)

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom, fileapi

Inside my HTML code I have following IMG tag:

```
<img src="picture.png"  id="picture" />
```

I would like to create in image Blob object (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) (to use it further in FirefoxOS web activity) having it's uri ("picture.png"). I guess I need the method which works in opposite way  to URL.createObjectURL:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL

Answer (score 7):

The Fetch API is now suitable, as used in the docs:

[Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob

Simply:

```
fetch("picture.png")
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blob => {
    // use blob...
});
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for different origin requests because of CORS policy

Comment: Fetch also uses the `connect-src` CSP policy while `img` uses `image-src` which can easily trigger CSP failures

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a byte-by-byte copy of the image (e.g. if you don't mind that jpg is converted to png), then you can draw the image on a `<canvas>`, and use `.toBlob()` to get a blob for it.

If you need the original data as a blob, or if the image is hosted at a different origin, then you can use the code at https://stackoverflow.com/a/21136980 (for same-origin requests, just use `x.open('GET', 'picture.png');`).