# Using canvas to create desktop notification images, only one image works from background page

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas

I'm having an issue while using `canvas` in a background page to create data URLs for desktop notifications' images.

I want to use the "image" [notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications) which require a 3:2 ratio to display properly. The images I want to use (from hulu.com) are a different ratio, so I decided to use the `canvas` element to create the corresponding data URL off of these images so that the ratio is correct. It kind of works in theory, but…

…I'm having issues if I'm creating more than one canvas/notification in the background page. One image is created properly, but the rest comes out empty.

Confusingly, opening the same background page in a new tab (i.e. exact same code) makes everything works just fine: all the notifications are created with the images loaded from hulu.com. Also, just changing the dimensions from 360x240 to 300x200 makes it work. Finally, though they're similar computers with the same Chrome version (34.0.1847.116), it works without modification at work while it doesn't on my own laptop.

I made a test extension available at the bottom of this post. Basically, it only has a generated background page. The code for that page is this:

```
var images = ["http://ib2.huluim.com/video/60376901?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib2.huluim.com/video/60366793?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib4.huluim.com/video/60372951?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib1.huluim.com/video/60365336?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib3.huluim.com/video/60376290?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib4.huluim.com/video/60377231?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib4.huluim.com/video/60312203?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib1.huluim.com/video/60376972?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib4.huluim.com/video/60376971?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib1.huluim.com/video/60376616?size=290x160&img=1"];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    getDataURL(i);
}

/*
 * Gets the data URL for an image URL
 */
function getDataURL(i) {
    var img = new Image();

    img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = 360;
        canvas.height = 240;
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
        ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);
        var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        chrome.notifications.create('', {
            type: 'image',
            iconUrl: 'logo_128x128.png',
            title: String(i),
            message: 'message',
            imageUrl: dataURL
        }, function(id) {});
    }

    //img.src = chrome.extension.getURL('logo_128x128.png');;
    img.src = images[i];
}
```

The commented out line for `img.src = ...` is a test where it loads a local file instead of a remote one. In that case, all the images are created.

The red rectangle added to the canvas is to show that it's not just the remote image that is an issue: the whole resulting canvas is empty, without any red rectangle.

If you download and add the test extension below, you should get 10 notifications but only one with an image.

Then, to open the background page in a new tab, you can inspect the background page, type this in the console:

```
chrome.extension.getURL('_generated_background_page.html')
```

and right-click the URL, and click "Open in a new Tab" (or window). Once open you should get 10 notifications that look fine.

Any idea of what is going on? I haven't been able to find any kind of limitations for background pages relevant to that. Any help would be appreciated, because this has been driving me crazy!

Files available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ejbh6wq0qixb7a8/canvastest.zip

---

edit: based on @GameAlchemist's comment, I also tried the following: same `getDataURL` method, but the loop wrapped inside an `onload` for the logo:

```
function loop() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        getDataURL(i);
    }
}

var logo = new Image();
logo.onload = function () {
    loop();
}
logo.src = chrome.extension.getURL('logo_128x128.png');
```

Comment: first thing i would try, especially since it works with the commented line, is to have this code run only after logo_128x128.png was loaded.

Comment: Does switching to `persistent: true` for the background page in the manifest change the situation?

Comment: @GameAlchemist I'm not sure I understand what you mean: the code is already in `img.onload` in both cases. As a test I create a new `Image` object with the logo URL as `src` and the existing code wrapped in a function for `onload`, but it didn't work either.

Comment: @Xan for a second I thought it worked! But no, it's the same thing. Isn't `persistent: true` the default still? I thought it worked because somehow the first time I clicked "reload" after making the change, all the images loaded properly. Not sure what that tells us unfortunately.

Comment: maybe to make things clearer : have the while code above wrapped into the onload of logo_128x128.png. The idea is to be 100% sure logo_128x128.png is loaded.

Comment: Wait. I think I know what's wrong. Your `var img` is local to `getDataURL`, and no other references to it exist. As soon as the function exits, the garbage collector is free to kill it. You have a race condition that works sometimes. Use an array of Images in the global scope and see if it helps.

Comment: @Xan : img has an (onload) event handler hooked, which will make it stay alive. After onload triggered, in deed img will disapear, but the only object that matters now is imageUrl == dataUrl, and it is stored in the notification objects.

Comment: @GameAlchemist I updated the question to show the change I made. I think that's what you're talking about.

Comment: @TimothéeBoucher : so you changed the code, but what was the outcome ? (negative i guess).

Comment: @GameAlchemist oh yeah, that didn't work either :) (that was the code I tried from my earlier comment, sorry I wasn't clear) Just to make sure, I also added a `console.log(img)` in the `onload` to add a reference to `img`. Indeed it's printing the proper thing. (i.e. the object hasn't been garbage collected yet)

Comment: In fact i wonder quite the same type of things as @Xan (too aggresive g.c.), but about the dataURL var. I'd try to push the dataURL in a global array as they are built to see if something changes.

Comment: @GameAlchemist This is getting excessively long, let us [continue in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51443/discussion-on-using-canvas-to-create-desktop-notification-images)

Comment: @TimothéeBoucher I think that you're better off with using `FileReader` to get a base64-encoded picture. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21136980/938089 for sample code. The canvas thing in your question is weird, if it's a bug, report it at http://crbug.com/new. Have you already tried to set the `.height` and `.width` properties of the `HTMLImageElement` object?

Comment: @RobW adding `.height` and `.width` didn't help and neither did `FileReader`. Though for `FileReader` it sometimes loads everything fine when I reload the test extension but if I reload it or if I call the loop again, it doesn't work. But same thing: with the page opened in a tab, no problemo… I'll play around with it a bit more and file a bug. It's strange.

Comment: I ended up trying with hardcoded data URLs and it was still an issue, so I filed a bug for Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=370755 Thanks all of you for your help! I'll update here if it's confirmed, fixed, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that the create() method is asynchronous and you should use a callback with. The callback can invoke next image fetching.

I would suggest doing this in two steps:

1. Load all the images first
2. Process the image queue

The reason is that you can utilize the asynchronous image loading better this way instead of chaining the callbacks which would force you to load one and one image.

For example:

### Image loader

```
var urls = ["http://ib2.huluim.com/video/60376901?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib2.huluim.com/video/60366793?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib4.huluim.com/video/60372951?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib1.huluim.com/video/60365336?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib3.huluim.com/video/60376290?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib4.huluim.com/video/60377231?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib4.huluim.com/video/60312203?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib1.huluim.com/video/60376972?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib4.huluim.com/video/60376971?size=290x160&img=1",
    "http://ib1.huluim.com/video/60376616?size=290x160&img=1"];

var images = [],            // store image objects
    count = urls.length;    // for loader

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    var img = new Image;         // create image
    img.onload = loader;         // share loader handler
    img.src = urls[i];           // start loading
    images.push(img);            // push image object in array
}

function loader() {
    count--;
    if (count === 0) process();  // all loaded, start processing
}
//TODO need error handling here as well
```

**[Fiddle with concept code for loader](http://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/YHvK2/)**

### Processing

Now the processing can be isolated from the loading:

```
function process() {

    // share a single canvas (use clearRect() later if needed)
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        current = 0;

    canvas.width = 360;
    canvas.height = 240;

    createImage();             // invoke processing for first image

    function createImage() {

        ctx.drawImage(images[current], 0, 0); // draw current image
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
        ctx.fillRect (10, 10, 55, 50);

        chrome.notifications.create('', {
            type    : 'image',
            iconUrl : 'logo_128x128.png',
            title   : String(i),
            message : 'message',
            imageUrl: canvas.toDataURL()  // png is default

        },
        function(id) {                    // use callback
            current++;                    // next in queue
            if (current < images.length) {
                createImage();            // call again if more images
            }
            else {
                done();                   // we're done -> continue to done()
            }
        });
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer: I don't have a test environment to test Chrome extensions so typos/errors may be present.*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Epistemex! At some point I thought about doing it this way (loading all images first, then the notifications) but I might have never got around to test it. I can't test it right now either since my work computer doesn't complain with my current version. Wrt `String(i)` I *was* using the reserved keyword: the `title` attribute needs to be a string and `i` is an integer.

Comment: @TimothéeBoucher ah. of course, my bad there for a moment. I also forgot to mention possible CORS issues. If the images are loaded from external server you may get a security error (when calling toDataURL). If you know the (if remote) images allows CORS usage just ignore - otherwise cors requst must be issued when loading the image and the remote server must allow it. Let me know and I'll include a little more about this in the answer.

Comment: CORS shouldn't be an issue with Chrome Extensions, it is ignored for hosts for which there is permission.

Comment: @Xan yeah, I wasn't 100% sure. Thanks.

Comment: Sadly, that didn't seem to work either. One test I'll try to do tonight is to forego the image loading and to have the data URL hardcoded and see if the issue could be at that level. If that doesn't work, the issue is more on the notifications side than with canvas. Since `FileReader` didn't work either, this is likely the case.